# Sound card not detected

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on new computer. I have soundcard integrated in motherboard MSI B150M Pro-vd but my sound card is not detected. How do I get configs/drivers to get it to work.

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device f996
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at df220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at df200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbb (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 3683
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at df080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a170] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:f996]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3683]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

`uname -r`:

```
3.19.0-49-generic
```

Comment: What's the output of `uname -r` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Device a170" shows that your distribution's `lspci` doesn't yet know the PCI ID of that device, so it's likely that the kernel driver does not know it either.

Consider using a more modern distribution, or at least [update the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade).